# How to add package declaration for antlr3 generated classes using ant?

Tags: ant, antlr, antlr3

My build.xml looks like following:

```
<property name="lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />
<property name="src" value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="package" value="com/package/antlr" />

<path id="compile.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib}">
        <include name="antlr-3.5-complete.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- Check if ANTLR3 can be found in the classpath -->
<target name="antlr_classpath">

    <whichresource property="antlr.in.classpath" class="org.antlr.Tool">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="compile.classpath" />
        </classpath>
    </whichresource>
    <fail message="ANTLR3 not found in CLASSPATH">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <isset property="antlr.in.classpath" />
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <echo>ANTLR3 found via CLASSPATH</echo>
</target> 


<!-- Antlr3 is called here -->

<target name="antlr" depends="antlr_classpath">
    <java classname="org.antlr.Tool" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="compile.classpath" />
        </classpath>
        <arg value="-verbose" />
        <arg value="-make"/>
        <arg value="-o" />
        <arg path="${src}/${package}" />
        <arg path="${src}/${package}/BoolExpr.g" />
    </java>
</target>
```

It generates BoolExprLexer.java and BoolExprParser.java in folder /src/com/package/antlr, which is what i want, but files generated belong to default package. How can I make'em part of com.package.antlr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANTLR 3**

For a lexer grammar or parser grammar, add the following to your grammar file:

```
@header {
    package com.package.antlr;
}
```

For a combined grammar (lexer and parser in the same grammar file), add the following to your grammar file:

```
@lexer::header {
    package com.package.antlr;
}

@parser::header {
    package com.package.antlr;
}
```

**ANTLR 4**

Pass the following argument to the ANTLR tool when you generate your lexer/parser from the grammar:

```
-package com.package.antlr
```

This can be done during an Ant build by adding the following two lines to your build script:

```
    <arg value="-package"/>
    <arg value="com.package.antlr" />
```